# how given a family of orthonormal functions on $[0..2\pi]$, modify this family to work on $[0..\ell]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\varphi_0(x), \varphi_1(x), ...$ are orthonormal functions on $[0..2\pi]$

How can I find an orthonormal family of functions working on $[0..\ell]$ and what is the intuition behind looking for such a modification?

(I know that the answer is $\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\ell}}\varphi_n(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell})$, but I can't come up with intuition and a correct path leading there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squish or stretch their graphs horizontally so that their entire domain goes from $[0, 2\pi]$ to $[0, \ell]$. This is done by changing the argument to $\phi_n\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)$. Substitution shows that they are still orthogonal. However, they aren't normalized any more:
$$
\int_0^\ell\phi_n\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\cdot \phi_n\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\ell}{2\pi}\phi_m\left(x\right)\cdot \phi_n\left(x\right)dx
$$

Squish or stretch their graphs vertically so that they are normalized. This is done by multiplying each one by $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\ell}}$, cancelling out the substitution factor above. This doesn't change the fact that they are pairwise orthogonal, and they are now also normalized. Thus they are orthonormal.

Comment: Looks legit in case the integral equality is true. But why $\int_0^\ell\phi_n\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\cdot \phi_n\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\ell}{2\pi}\phi_m\left(x\right)\cdot \phi_n\left(x\right)dx$ ?

Comment: @OleksandrKhryplyvenko That's simple substitution $x\mapsto \frac{\ell x}{2\pi}$, giving $dx\mapsto \frac{\ell}{2\pi}dx$ and taking the integration bounds from $0, \ell$ to $0, 2\pi$. I could have changed integration variable to make it a bit more visible, but you used $x$ both before and after domain change in your question, so I kept it.

Comment: No stretch needed. Change of var & proper grouping allows to deduce $\psi_i$: $\int_0^{2\pi} \varphi_i(g)\varphi_i(g)dg = 1 = \int_0^{\ell}\varphi_i\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\varphi_i\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell} \right)'dx = \int_0^{\ell}\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi}{\ell} \right)}\varphi_i\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right) \sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi}{\ell} \right)}\varphi_i\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)dx$, where $g(x)=\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}$. so we deduce $\psi_i(x)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi}{\ell} \right)}\varphi_i\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\ell}\right)$

Comment: Your intuition with change of variable(which does the stretching itself: we look for such change of variable, which will have range $[0..\ell]$) really helped! Thank you once again!

Comment: not range, but domain. Sorry for typo.

Comment: @OleksandrKhryplyvenko If you can deduce the square rooted term directly from the substitution integral without having to think geometrically about vertically stretching the graph, then that's all good.